# What could be the cause of phantom pain?

Tags: training, pain

I am new to cycling, after doing my usual route, the next few days I feel like a phantom pain in my calves and thighs if I do not use them (like running or cycling).

Could anybody shed some light on this annoying pain?

Cheers!

Comment: New to cycling and its uncomfortable?  Stop pushing so hard.  Relax in your riding.  Do check your saddle height is right though.

Comment: My setup is good since I went through some trial and error until I felt comfortable with the saddle height and got used to not touching the ground with my whole foot. But thanks for the comment ;*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call it [muscle pain, or myalgia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myalgia) from using muscles you did not train before.
It is normal that it disappears when you are using the muscles as this kind of pain is one that will 'go away when you do more'.

If it is a light aching, I would just ignore it and go on with your current training schedule.
If it is painfull enough to keep you awake or keep your attention while doing things, slow down on the cycling and do not do as much or take more time in between sessions.

Comment: Yeah, I would define it more near a light aching than pure pain. Since if I fidget my leg it mostly goes away. I will continue going with the current pace and see what happens :D Thanks a lot ;*

Comment: Phantom pain or phantom sensations are something amputees experience - it's a pain or sensation experienced in a non existent limb or organ. I get such sensations regularly, sometimes painful but fortunately not too bad too often.